# Change the cursor when UI is busy

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have this class:

```
public class CursorWait : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public CursorWait(int showAfter)
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(showAfter, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(delegate(Task task)
        {
            if (!task.IsCanceled)
                Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Wait);
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
    }
}
```

To use it like this :

```
using (new CursorWait(showAfter: 500))
{
    DoSomethingMayBeHeavyOrNotInUI(); 
}
```

However is not working since the Mouse.SetCursor relies in the UI thread to change it, and since it is busy, it will never change, so how can I change the cursor ?

**Note**: I know I should not be blocking the UI thread and instead just changing the property IsHitTestVisible of the window.  but I'm new at this project and my team made the things this way, and they won't let me since the project is almost finished

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line After setting the mouse cursor.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
```

Comment: when I said "Mouse.SetCursor relies in the UI thread" I meant that I won't change because the UI thread is busy, doing an invoke won't make it less busy

Comment: My understanding is that this line is the rough equivalent of Application.DoEvents from forms based applications.  It should make your UI thread process any pending window messages, which includes changing the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
        // your code
    }));
```

or

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            // your code
        }));
```

More information at: [MSDN - Dispatcher.Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)